# aws - elastic beanstalk - eb deploy not running node script servers after environment rebuild

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using eb cli to deploy my app. This is my eb config.

```
branch-defaults:
  master:
    environment: stage
    group_suffix: null
environment-defaults:
  stage:
    branch: null
    repository: null
global:
  application_name: appName
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: someKey
  default_platform: Node.js 12 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2
  default_region: us-east-2
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: eb-cli
  repository: null
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application
```

My app package.json looks like this

```
{
  "name": "appName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.656.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "socket.io": "latest",
    "tail": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  }
}
```

Normally after I was using eb deploy, the command node app.js was run, starting the server and all was well. The problem is that afer I rebuilt the environment today the command is not run any more (it doesn't fail, is not run at all). Google seems to fail me on this matter. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried using `eb deploy` with either `--debug` or `--verbose` options for more info?

Comment: Yes, the command is not run, no errors, nor fails, nothing. Total silence. I terminated the environment and created it again and things work as expected, but no idea what happened and would really like to know :).

Comment: Don't know. You can monitor the situation and if it happens again than maybe have to look more deeply into it.